# Why should I have recommended to delete this answer?

Tags: support, low-quality-posts, disputed-review-audits

I just failed [this review audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/7099558) from the Low Quality Posts queue.  [The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28108451/426671) was:

> [image]

Even if the link was removed, it is still helpful, so it is not a link-only answer.

The audit failure message tells me, in part:

> This post has severe quality issues. It is abusive nonsense, noise, spam, blatantly off-topic or otherwise irredeemable – readers will find it offensive or repulsive rather than helpful.

Which makes no sense to me; the post seemed genuinely helpful.

Why (if at all) should I have recommended this post be deleted?

Comment: From the audit's perspective, "because a mod deleted it." So your real question is why did the mod delete it.

Comment: From what I see, I don't agree with "readers will find it offensive or repulsive rather than helpful." but it is telling the OP that he **must** use the very thing that he wants to avoid (even though other answers seem to think otherwise) then points to a blog, possibly the authors (I don't know).

Comment: If you go to the question, the text of the answer is hidden and replaced with text noting that it is either spam or offensive, and since it isn't offensive... maybe it's spam? Doesn't immediately look like spam to me, but i haven't followed the link.

Comment: It was marked as spam. I'm just completely guessing here, but the particular user might have got the mod's attention by posting other spammy posts and this one got caught in the resulting removals since it has a link.

Comment: There were some spam flags involved with this post and some other ones by this user, looking into this though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28108451/426671) was flagged as spam because the user had posted several similar spam-like answers in a very short timeframe, that answer and the others were all deleted by a moderator. The deletion marked the flags as helpful, and resulted in the answers being included as an audit.

We have received the answers again posted by this user and most don't belong, but they don't seem to deserve the spam flag, so those flags have been cleared.  This should stop those answers from appearing as audits.